# Updating types during type inference in a Hindley-Milner type system

Tags: type-checking, type-inference

I'm looking at implementing type inference for a Hindley-Milner type system, and before I have even started to implement the Damas-Milner algorithm, while working through some examples, I hit some stumbling blocks.

I'm trying to follow some notes on the algorithm. Given the following program:

```
let id x = x
  in id id
```

I first use the pseudo code for the `letfn` case:

1. Create a new type variable for the function type: `funType := α`
2. Create a new type variable for the argument type: `argType := β`
3. Infer the return type:

   1. Extend the (empty) type environment for the function body to be `functionBodyTypeEnv := ['x' → β, 'id' → α]`
   2. Look up the return type and find it to be `β`: `returnType := β`
4. Note down the constraint that the function type and (argument → result) type must be the same: `α = β → β`

Okay. So far so good. We now have a type for the function (`α`) and also have found one constraint: `α = β → β`. Now let's infer the type of the `let`'s body (which will be the type of the full program):

4. Extend the (empty again) type environment with the *generalized* type of the function so we get `letBodyTypeEnv := ['id' → ∀α.α]` ⚠️
5. Infer the type of the `let` body, which is a `call` with of 'id' (function) with 'id' (argument):

   1. Find the type of the variable 'id' (function) to be `∀α.α` and instantiate/specialize this to be `γ`: `funType := γ` (there are no free type variables, so it's a monotype) ⚠️
   2. Same as above: Find the type of the variable 'id' (argument) to be `∀α.α` and instantiate this to be `δ`: `argType := δ` ⚠️
   3. Create a new type variable for the return type: `returnType:= ε`
   4. Note down the constraint that the function type and the (argument → result) type must be equal: `γ = δ → ε`
   5. Return the result type as the type of the `let` body: `return ε`

So at this point we have the type `ε` for the full program and have recorded the constraints [`α = β → β`, `γ = δ → ε`]. However, this is (obviously) wrong and I suspect that the problem is with step 4, 5.1 and 5.2.

In step 4 we have the type of the function 'id' as α and generalize it to be `∀α.α` before inferring the type of the `let body`. However, if instead of just “noting down” that `α = β → β` we *replaced* `α` by `β → β` in the type environment of the `let` body, we would have inferred the type `β → β` in step 5.1 and 5.2 – and that would have been the (correct) type of the program.

Are my observations correct? If so, should I always replace a type variable with the type it's equal to when finding such a constraint?